# Android getOrientation() returns azimuth, positive or negative?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation

**Assumption**: the phone is held flat (parallel with the ground).

I am using `getRotationMatrix()` and `getOrientation (float[] R, float[] values)` to get the azimuth. Under this assumption, the azimuth is simply `values[0]`.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) says:

> All three angles above are in radians and positive in the
>   counter-clockwise direction.

Then I checked, when my phone's y axis points to the **North**, the azimuth is indeed **0**.

However, here comes the problem: when my phone's y axis points to **West**, i.e. **I rotated my phone counter-clockwise** to make it point from North to West, the azimuth is **negative**!

**Shouldn't the angle be positive when it is rotated counter-clockwise from North?**

Where goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if the positive direction of Z points to the sky then when y axis points to West then the angle is positive. But the coordinate used in getOrientation the positive direction of Z points down to the earth, thus now what seems counter-clockwise becomes clockwise, so West is negative.

Comment: Makes sense. So if my phone's y axis points up, then West should be negative right?

Comment: If you mean the phone is held vertical with y-axis points up then it does not make sense to talk about the direction of the y-axis as East, West, North or South. If reference to direction as compass, East is positive and West is negative.

Comment: Sorry for the typo! I mean my phone z points up.  I hold phone like a compass.

Comment: Think of a person rotating a loop counterclockwise, if you stand opposite to this person the rotation you see is clockwise. Yes, the z-coordinate of the device as return by the sensors is opposite to the z-coordinate when calculating the azimuth, so it is confusing. When the screen is up, West is negative.

Comment: So the coordinate system in use isn't RHS but  LHS: x, y, -z?

Comment: You have to be standing 'behind' the arrow that it rotates around. Not in front of it. Z is coming towards you, so you have to stand behind your phone.

Comment: It is independent of where you stand, it depend on how the phone is held