# Android getOrientation() azimuth results don't match docs

Tags: java, android

So, I'm trying to get the azimuth between my phone and magnetic North. Like so:

```
float[] rotation = new float[9];
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, null, lastMag, lastAcc);

float[] orientation = new float[3];
SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);

if (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - lastTime / 1000 > 0) {
    Log.d("MonitorService", "Current azimuth: " + String.valueOf(orientation[0]));
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

I'm reading the docs for `getOrientation()` and I find this definition for azimuth, which comes from `orientation[0]`:

> values[0]: Azimuth, angle of rotation about the -z axis. This value represents the angle between the device's y axis and the magnetic north pole. When facing north, this angle is 0, when facing south, this angle is π. Likewise, when facing east, this angle is π/2, and when facing west, this angle is -π/2. The range of values is -π to π.

The docs clearly state that when the Y axis is pointed East, I should be seeing **positive** values, and when pointed West, I should be seeing **negative** values.

*However*, the behavior I'm seeing is precisely the opposite! When I point my phone's Y axis to the East (e.g., screen up, top of screen pointed East, or screen down, top of screen pointed East), I get **negative** azimuth values!

Am I thinking about this correctly? Can somebody explain where my logic is wrong here?

Also, yes, I'm aware there's a related question here: [Android getOrientation() returns azimuth, positive or negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182442/android-getorientation-returns-azimuth-positive-or-negative?rq=1)

However, I believe my question is unique because:

- The question is from 2013, and based on the way the question quotes the docs, it seems that the docs have been rewritten in the intervening time.
- The  docs have been rewritten to give specific examples of output, *examples that appear in my experience to be incorrect*.

Comment: Check your param order to `getRotationMatrix()`

Comment: Wow, yep, that would be it. I had checked that I wasn't swapping the Inclination and Rotation matrix parameters, but I didn't think to check if I was swapping the accelerometer and gyroscope. Wild that it was giving me sane (although flipped) output for azimuth given the circumstances... it'll take some noodling to figure out why that was still the case. At any rate, it's all fixed now. Thanks!